# Problem accessing attributes in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, attributes, beautifulsoup

I am having problems using Python (2.7). The code basically consists of:

```
str = '<el at="some">ABC</el><el>DEF</el>'
z = BeautifulStoneSoup(str)

for x in z.findAll('el'):
    # if 'at' in x:
    # if hasattr(x, 'at'):
        print x['at']   
    else:
        print 'nothing'
```

I expected the first `if` statement to work correctly (ie: if `at` doesn't exist, print `"nothing"`), but it always prints nothing (ie: is always `False`). The second `if` on the other hand is always `True`, which will cause the code to raise a `KeyError` when trying to access `at` from the second `<el>` element, which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: `str` is not your best choice for a varible name, as it masks the builtin str type - how about something like `xmltext`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `in` operator is for sequence and mapping types, what makes you think the object returned by `BeautifulSoup` is supposed to implement it correctly? According to the BeautifulSoup docs, you should access attributes using the `[]` syntax.

Re `hasattr`, I think you confused HTML/XML attributes and Python object attributes. `hasattr` is for the latter, and BeaitufulSoup AFAIK doesn't reflect the HTML/XML attributes it parsed in its own object attributes.

P.S. note that the `Tag` object in `BeautifulSoup` *does* implement `__contains__` - so maybe you're trying with the wrong object? Can you show a complete but minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

---

Running this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

str = '<el at="some">ABC</el><el>DEF</el>'
z = BeautifulSoup(str)

for x in z.findAll('el'):
    print type(x)
    print x['at']
```

I get:

```
<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
some
<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soup4.py", line 8, in <module>
    print x['at']
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'at'
```

Which is what I expected. The first `el` has a `at` attribute, the second doesn't - and this throws a `KeyError`.

---

Update 2: the `BeautifulSoup.Tag.__contains__` looks inside the *contents* of the tag, not its attributes. To check if an attribute exists use `in`.

Comment: `in` is also part of the mapping interface and refers to the key in those cases.

Comment: The problem with that is accessing an element that doesn't exist will raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: @Null: `hasattr` is very different from accessing an "attribute" via `[]`. I'll edit my answer to clarify

Comment: Also, I read the documentation and `in` can be defined for user-defined classes if they implement the `__contains__()` magic method; so I would expect BeautifulSoup to have done it - especially because as far as I can remember it was working correctly.

Comment: @NullUserException: why expect it? just read the docs of the module and work according to them. For full enlightment, go over the source of BeautifulSoup

Comment: It's just that code that was previously working fine broke, so I was wondering what the hell was going on. I'll go and read BeautifulSoup's source.

Comment: @Null: see my updated answer - I looked in the code, `Tag` implements `__contains__`, so did you try a wrong object?

Comment: So what I *should* do is just to use a try catch block? I was hoping the a test like `if 'at' in x` would save me the trouble of having to do that.

Comment: @NullUserException: you can use `has_key` - I updated the answer again. `__contains__`, and hence `in` are for searching in the contents of a tag, not its attributes

Comment: `has_key` has been removed in Python 3. Use `dict.get(key, default=None)`.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is as simple as you provided, you can solve it in a compact way with:

```
for x in z.findAll('el'):
    print x.get('at', 'nothing')
```

Answer (score 1):

To just scan for an element by tag name, a pyparsing solution might be more readable (and without using deprecated API's like `has_key`):

```
from pyparsing import makeXMLTags

# makeXMLTags creates a pyparsing expression that matches tags with
# variations in whitespace, attributes, etc.
el,elEnd = makeXMLTags('el')

# scan the input text and work with elTags
for elTag, tagstart, tagend in el.scanString(xmltext):
    if elTag.at:
        print elTag.at
```

For an added refinement, pyparsing allows you to define a filtering parse action so that tags will only match if a particular attribute-value (or attribute-anyvalue) is found:

```
# import parse action that will filter by attribute
from pyparsing import withAttribute

# only match el tags having the 'at' attribute, with any value
el.setParseAction(withAttribute(at=withAttribute.ANY_VALUE))

# now loop again, but no need to test for presence of 'at'
# attribute - there will be no match if 'at' is not present
for elTag, tagstart, tagend in el.scanString(xmltext):
    print elTag.at
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the get() method for accessing attribute

```
link = soup.find('a')
href = link.get('href')
name = link.get('name')

if name:
    print 'anchor'
if href:
    print 'link'
```